# Fingerprint reader on the T60 Thinkpad running 10.10

Tags: fingerprint-reader

How do I get my fingerprint reader working on my T60 Thinkpad running Ubuntu 10.10. There seems to many ideas out there but I am not sure what to do to get it working for logins.
Thanks Jim W.

Comment: ... maybe you should edit into your question the "ideas" you have been investigating so that you dont get the same ideas as answers.

Answer (score 1):

FINGERPRINT AUTHENTICATION FOR UBUNTU BASED ON FPRINTD

1. Add this PPA to your sources:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fprint`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

1. Install the software:

`sudo apt-get install libfprint0 fprint-demo libpam-fprintd gksu-polkit`

[source](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fprint)